# How to disable GoGuardian on personal computer

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

I have a windows computer with Chrome. I signed into Chrome with my school account, and now all the teachers can see whatever I was doing on my personal computer. Obviously, Chrome will not let me turn it off. Is there anyway to block extensions outside of Chrome?

Comment: You should be able to sign out of your account

Comment: And create new ptifile if desired.

Comment: But if I sign out of my account, then I cannot access my schoolwork on my personal computer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot do that. Since GoGuardian is linked to your school Google account, you would have to remove it entirely. However, they can't track your other Google accounts or your computer usage.